# Separating address column into multiple columns in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a dataset that has an `address` column for `400` records. I would like to split this column into multiple columns.

Sample data

```
        Full_Address = c("1111 Harding St Hollywood, FL 33024",
                         "2222 W Broward Blvd Plantation, 33317",
                         "3333 SW 74 Ave Davie, 33314",
                         "4444 Thomas Street Hollywood, FL 33024",
                         "11111 Lake Road (SW 12 Street) Davie, 33325",
                         "555 Bryan Blvd Plantation, 33317",
                         "5555 NW 71 Ter Parkland, 33067",
    "7777 N Oakland Forest Dr Oakland Park, 33309,
"888 Some Ave Pines Pembroke Pines, 33346",
"9999 Some Blvd Hallandale Beach, 33365",
"4440 Some 123 Ave Pompano Beach, 33389")
```

Desired Columns

```
        ID = c("1111",
              "2222",
              "3333",
              "4444",
              "11111",
              "555",
              "5555",
    "7777",
"888",
"9999",
"4440")
        
        Street_Address = c("Harding St",
                           "W Broward Blvd",
                           "SW 74 Ave",
                           "Thomas Street",
                           "Lake Road (SW 12 Street)",
                           "Bryan Blvd",
                          "NW 71 Ter",
    "N Oakland Forest Dr",
"Some Ave Pines",
"Some Blvd",
"Some 123 Ave")

        City = c("Hollywood",
                 "Plantation",
                "Davie",
                "Hollywood",
                "Davie",
                "Plantation",
               "Parkland",
    "Oakland Park",
"Pembroke Pines",
"Hallandale Beach",
"Pompano Beach")
        
        Zipcode = c("33024",
                    "33317",
                    "33314",
                    "33024",
                    "33325",
                    "33317",
                    "33067",
    "33309",
"33346",
"33365",
"33389")
```

How can I do this in `R` via `tidyr`?

Code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)

df = Full_Address

df = df %>% tidyr::separate( c("ID", "Street_Address", "City", "Zipcode"), 
                sep =  , extra = "merge")) # stuck at this step.....
```

Comment: Well you can always take the last string before a comma as the city. But waht if a city has two name component?? Does your data has that?

Comment: @KU99 yes it does have such names such as `Pembroke Pines` or `Oakland Park`.

Comment: So how will you know when a city has two words or when a city has one word? Any particular logic? eg For someone who is not from `Pembroke Pines` they cannot tell as to whether the city has 2 words in its name

Comment: @KU99, well there are multiple cities with two words, maybe the code could have those last names or full names of cities with two words to match them? It's a county dataset that has `32` cities in total.

Comment: There is no logic to it eg `123 Road Pines` vs `123 Pembroke Pines` . There is no way to tell that the first Pines while the second is Pembroke Pines. Unless you have a list of all the cities/ cities with 2 names separately that can be matched to your full address

Comment: @KU99 How about for example converting first the city name in `7777 N Oakland Forest Dr Oakland Park, 33309` to `7777 N Oakland Forest Dr Oakland-Park, 33309`? Then `Oakland-Park` in the new `City` column could be converted back to `Oakland Park`?

Comment: The moment you are converting it means you already know its two name. Ans that is where the issue lies. Think of a scenario where you do not know

Comment: @KU99 how about `splitting` `numbers` and `strings` in the `addresses` into individual columns and then merging them accordingly. But I guess that won't work either as there would be addresses with different number of words, so there would be a mismatch while merging the columns. I am sorry but I am running out of ideas.

Comment: There is no way to tackle the city. Unless the address has a particular format eg ends with Boulevard(Blvd), Road(Rd), Street(St.), Avenue(Av, Ave.), Drive (Dr) etc then you can write a parser. But with the nknown formulation, you cannot tell when the street ends and the city starts. The rest you can tell

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is taking a city to only have one Name: cities like `New York` `Los Angeles` will not be matched.

```
data.frame(Full_Address) %>% 
  extract(Full_Address, c("ID", "Street_Address", "City", "Zipcode"), 
          '(\\d+) ([^,]+) (\\w+),\\D+(\\d+)')

     ID           Street_Address       City Zipcode
1  1111               Harding St  Hollywood   33024
2  2222           W Broward Blvd Plantation   33317
3  3333                SW 74 Ave      Davie   33314
4  4444            Thomas Street  Hollywood   33024
5 11111 Lake Road (SW 12 Street)      Davie   33325
6   555               Bryan Blvd Plantation   33317
7  5555                NW 71 Ter   Parkland   33067
```

Comment: what if after the above code is run, another piece of code can be added that says if a `row` in the `City` column has `New` and `Los` then add ` York` and ` Angeles` to them respectively to make those row values `New York` and `Los Angeles`?

Comment: @Mandalorian that will just be for the two there is `Las Vegas` `San Francisco`, `Salt Lake City` (3 words), `San Diego`, `Kettle Falls`, `St. Paul` (This makes it even harder to distinguish between Street(St) and the city name St Paul, `Canyon Country` etc etc. One need a separate list that contain US city names that can be used to merge the list one has